# singularity of $f(z)={(z-1)\over (e^{2\pi i\over z}-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**$f(z)={(z-1)\over (e^{2\pi i\over z}-1)}$**

Then which of the following is/are true?

1. $f$ has an isolated singularity at $0$
2. $f$ has an removable singularity at $1$
3. $f$ has infinitely many poles
4. each pole  is of order 1.

I wrote that $3$ is correcct as at $z={1\over n}$ we see that $f(z)=\infty$, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

The denominator vanishes for $1/z=k$ for $k$ integer and has zeros of order one because the derivative is $-2\pi ie^{2\pi i/z}/z^2$, which doesn't vanish. At zero is has an essential singularity [depending on the book you use].

Therefore (1) is false [notice the poles are accumulating at zero], (2) is true, (3) is true, and (4) is true.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you please explain the first two points to me.

Comment: @KprimeX Which first two points? The singularity of $f$ at $0$ is non-isolated, since $f$ has poles at $1/k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0,1\}$. At $1$, $f$ has a removable singularity, since both, numerator and denominator, have a simple zero there.

Comment: Yes exactly those two points. thanks got it @DanielFischer