# Let $f(z)=\frac{1-z}{ (e^{2\pi i/z-1)}}$, then which of the following are true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $$f(z)=\frac{1-z}{ (e^{2\pi i/z}-1)}$$
Then,

1. $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z=0$
2. $f$ has an removable singularity at $z=1$
3. $f$ has infinitely many poles
4. each pole of $f$ is of order $1$

This question is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629327/singularity-of-fz-z-1-over-e2-pi-i-over-z-1). I know $4$ is true but couldn't understand the explanations given for the others options. Please help me to understand these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is wrong, the rest are true.

To prove 2, notice that the denominator has a simple root at 1. It cancels with the root of the numerator.

To prove the rest, find poles by solving $e^{2\pi i/z}=1$. (If you are not sure how to solve this, look at the first chapter of your textbook where $e^z$ is explained). You wil find infnitelymany solutions tending to $0$; this proves that 1 is wrong, while 3 is correct.

To show 4 find mutiplicity of those poles by differentiating the denominator.